# passing bash variables to ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

```
ssh pvuser@host '. ~pvuser/.profile;/opt/datamart/bin/resmgr -import segp 

-colNames "npath cond type" -line "~Thresholds~Transmission_Auto|_|$r|_|rule|_|"'
```

I am having trouble trying to pass the variable $r to ssh in my bash script above.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

can you try this?

```
ssh pvuser@host ". ~pvuser/.profile;/opt/datamart/bin/resmgr -import segp -colNames \"npath cond type\" -line \"~Thresholds~Transmission_Auto|_|$r|_|rule|_|\""
```